# Expander View connected with NotifyCollectionChangedAction randomly expands items

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone 8 application I've created truly observable collection for noticing when item changes in collection. Here is collection code:

```
public class TrulyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TrulyObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
        CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(TrulyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void TrulyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                var test = item as INotifyPropertyChanged;
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnCollectionChanged(a);

    }
}
```

The situation which im going to describe happens for both controls: expander view (silverlight toolkit) and expander control (telerik controls). 
In my view I have list of expander views/controls. On Item tap event I would like to change something in tapped item and refresh list. Here is the code how i'm doing it:

ViewModel:

```
public TrulyObservableCollection<SymbolRecord> Symbols {get; set;}
private RelayCommand<SymbolRecord> tapCommand;
    public RelayCommand<SymbolRecord> TapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return tapCommand ?? (tapCommand = new RelayCommand<SymbolRecord>((item) =>
            {

                item.Symbol = "test";

            }));
        }

    }
```

View:

```
<telerikData:RadJumpList x:Name="ListControl" Grid.Row="1"IsCheckModeEnabled="False" GroupPickerItemTemplate="{StaticResource JumpListHeaderItemTemplate}"   GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource JumpListHeaderTemplate}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Symbols}"  >
<telerikData:RadJumpList.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <toolkit:ExpanderView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Expander="{Binding}"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ExpanderTemplate="{StaticResource ExpanderControlContentTemplate}" >
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView.Items> <TextBox Text="TEST"></TextBox></toolkit:ExpanderView.Items>
                    </toolkit:ExpanderView>                                
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
</telerikData:RadJumpList.ItemTemplate>
</telerikData:RadJumpList>
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger  EventName="ItemTap" SourceName="ListControl" >
            <cmd:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,
                                      ElementName=ListControl}"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When I click on item in emulator the property Symbol is changing but what's more **random items are being expanded**. Dont know why this is happening. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by refreshing your list?

Do you want to put some new data int it? If so there's no need to use TrulyObser... nor call CollectionChanged at all. Simply use methods like remove, add, insert etc.

Item template automatically get's as datacontext proper collection element. And binding works  normal. Simple INotifyCollectionChanged will be enough.

If you want to expand an expander do it in view's code-behind. If code-behind is something that you want to avoid create property IsExpanded in VM and bind it to Expander's IsExpanded property.

You can set your's VM IsExpanded property using that TrulyObservableCollection. When one of item's in the collection changed set it's IsExpanded to true.

Anyways. In most cases there's no need for "TrulyObservableCollection"